# Does the game really restart after 90 minutes?

Tags: antichamber

Does the game really reset after an hour and a half?

If it doesn't reset but does something cool instead, please leave that in a spoiler tag - I just want to know whether or not I'm going to lose my save and have to start over...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you won't have to start over. When the time is up, you can continue as if nothing happened. Completing the game in under 90 minutes is an optional bonus challenge you can take once you completed the game at a leisure pace.

Unless, of course, you think you are REALLY smart.

Comment: Completing as in getting to the end, if you just know the route, is easily possible in under 15 minutes : D - There is no in-game speedrunning challenge though, right? You don't get anything for it or see anything different?

Answer (score 8):

For completeness, here is the only thing that happens when time runs out:

*(potential spoiler, hover over to see image)*

> [image: Time's up!]